# Is it possible to override existing resource on Nexus when publishing its newer version using Gradle?

Tags: gradle, nexus

I had a very simple Gradle script to publish a library to Nexus using Gradle Maven Publish plugin. I got the following error when I reran the task :

```
Could not write to resource 'some_resource.pom'
```

I can delete it manually from the Nexus UI but I am wondering if there is a more programmatic way to do it. Btw, I do have write access to Nexus.

Comment: What version of Nexus Repository are you using? In theory you can set the repository to allow redeploy, however that sort of defeats the purpose of immutable artifacts (use at your own risk).

Comment: You can probably use the Restful API exposed by Nexus and write a task in Gradle to call it.